# Webview: How to zoom up to 100x?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

In my webview I have image in very high resolution ( 9000x5000px ).
So is there a way to zoom in in the webview up to 100x ?

I have used this code, but it allows me to zoom up to 10x:

```
// Enable Zoom
myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

Comment: use setInitialScale wth setLoadWithOverviewMode true

Answer (score 0):

Try This, It Might works for you.

```
// just set an Activity's content view to a single WebView for this test
WebView mWebview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(mWebview);

// retrieve the ZoomManager from the WebView
Class<?> webViewClass = mWebview.getClass();
Field mZoomManagerField = webViewClass.getDeclaredField("mZoomManager");
mZoomManagerField.setAccessible(true);
Object mZoomManagerInstance = mZoomManagerField.get(mWebview);

// modify the "default max zoom scale" value, which controls the upper limit
// and set it to something very large; e.g. Float.MAX_VALUE
Class<?> zoomManagerClass = Class.forName("android.webkit.ZoomManager");
Field mDefaultMaxZoomScaleField = zoomManagerClass.getDeclaredField("mDefaultMaxZoomScale");
mDefaultMaxZoomScaleField.setAccessible(true);
mDefaultMaxZoomScaleField.set(mZoomManagerInstance, Float.MAX_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your zoom level in setInitialScale() method.

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.setInitialScale(100);
```

Comment: You can use setScaleX() ans setScaleY() but you will have to choose proper scale value for X and Y